# svn diff without checkout

Tags: svn, diff

Is it possible to find out a recursive diff between two tags of a project in remote repository?

In other words if i know the location of 2 tags are https://myrepo.com/project/tags/v1 and https://myrepo.com/project/tags/v2 respectively, can i find the recursive diff between the 2 without having the code checked out on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svn diff` works with URLs, too. If you have the SVN command line tools already installed, all you have to do is to run:

```
svn diff https://myrepo.com/project/tags/v1 https://myrepo.com/project/tags/v2 > v1tov2.diff
```

After this `v1tov2.diff` will contain the unified diff between the two tags.

Comment: Ok I did this but the output has many details that I want to avoid. Can I just have file names from the output of this command?

Comment: When i do a svn diff --diff-cmd -x "-q" https://myrepo.com/project/tags/v1 https://myrepo.com/project/tags/v2 I get svn: Can't set process 'diff' child outfile: The parameter is incorrect. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: You may pass '--summarize' as an additional argument to `svn diff`. Then you get only the filenames and a code indication what happened with the file (added, modified, deleted). '--diff-cmd' is used for an entirely different purpose: this allows you to specify a external program which SVN will use to calculate the difference between two changed files. So don't pass the flag.

Comment: I tried svn diff --summarize and the output asks me to look at svn help which has no summarize option :(

Comment: I indeed used it for 2 URLs svn diff --summarize https://myrepo.com/project/tags/v1 https://myrepo.com/project/tags/v2 for example and the output:   svn: invalid option: --summarize
Type 'svn help' for usage.

Comment: This option was introduced in SVN 1.4. Do you use an older one? 1.7 is the current one.

Answer (score 0):

With the command line tool:

```
svn diff https://myrepo.com/project/tags/v1 https://myrepo.com/project/tags/v2
```